# calloc vs new for complicated structs in various compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-management, visual-studio-2017, undefined-behavior

I have the following struct:

```
struct MyNewShinyStruct
{
    int index;
    std::string name;
};
```

When `calloc`ing the above struct and then assigning values to `name`:

```
char letters[128]{"ABCDEFG"};
auto temp = static_cast<MyNewShinyStruct*>(calloc(2, sizeof(MyNewShinyStruct)));
temp[0].name = letters;
```

I should get in trouble for the above :-) (I should have used the `new` operator). 'calloc` zeroes out the allocated memory and does not calls the constructor of the struct/std::sting. But, from some unknown reason the above code works in VS2010/2013/2015 fails only in VS2017. It should always fail! What am I missing please?

P.S.
The above code was in production (compiled with VS2010) for many years and not even once a bug was reported that had to do with this code, not even once. It always worked.

Comment: `calloc` alone is not enough to create a non-pod type. `std::string` is not pod and by extension neither is `MyNewShinyStruct`. The result is undefined behavior and can't be meaningfully reasoned about.

Comment: Undefined behavior doesn't mean *always* fail. Sometimes it might also seem to work.

Comment: It's C++, use std::vector!

Comment: The part you left out of your demo is printing the contents of that string after you assign it. In Visual Studio 2017 it results in garbage.

Comment: @manni66 You are absolutely correct off course. I will use the usual argument: `its legacy code :-)`.

Comment: @BoPersson I've edited the original answer to emphasized that it really always worked.

Comment: _it really always worked_ bad luck. Start to fix it now.

Comment: @tar A compile error is no surprise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It should always fail! What am I missing please?

You missing the fact that UB does not mean "always fail". It could be anything, including expected behavior. To fix your program use placement new on the memory returned by calloc (assuming you have to use calloc for whatever reason, if you do not use `std::vector` instead). You should also understand that `std::string` most probably would allocate memory by itself and it is unlikely calloc unless you provide custom allocator.

Comment: 1. What us `UB`?

Comment: @RefaelSheinker Undefined behavior.

Comment: `To fix your program use placement new on the memory returned by calloc` - That is one option. But I will probably just replace the `calloc` entirely with `new` and be done with it,

Comment: @RefaelSheinker you better use `std::vector`, or at least use smart pointers with `new`

Comment: @Slava You are absolutely correct off course. I will use the usual argument: `its legacy code :-)`.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker https://ideone.com/eNQZjc  Use placement new then.. Note: You have to manually call the destructor.. You're causing yourself a lot more of a headache.. Even legacy C++ doesn't NEED malloc or calloc. It's C++, use new.